# Find word before and after delimiter

Tags: python, string, delimiter

```
string = "The is a better :: sentence as :: compared to that"
```

Output:

1. better sentence
2. as compared

I've tried the following,

```
string.split(" :: "), 
re.sub("[\<].*?[\>]", "", string)
```

These won't give me specific words

Comment: What have you tried?  What code did _you_ write which isn't working?

Comment: that won't work @erip he wants the word before and after the delim as each output.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy I was too quick to be a smartass. :) Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> string = "The is a better :: sentence as :: compared to that" 
>>> x = [' '.join(x) for x in map(lambda x: (x[0].split()[-1], x[1].split()[0]), zip(string.split('::')[:-1], string.split('::')[1:]))]
>>> x
```

Output:

```
['better sentence', 'as compared']
```

---

Disection:

First, split based on `::` and zip group successive matches

```
pairs = zip(string.split('::')[:-1], string.split('::')[1:]))
```

If you `list()` that expression, you get:

```
[('The is a better ', ' sentence as '), (' sentence as ', ' compared to that')]
```

Next, apply a function to extract the last word from the 1st element and the first word from the 2nd element each tuple:

```
new_pairs = map(lambda x: (x[0].split()[-1], x[1].split()[0]), pairs)
```

If you `list()` that expression, you get:

```
[('better', 'sentence'), ('as', 'compared')]
```

Lastly, join each tuple in a list comprehension:

```
result = [' '.join(x) for x in new_pairs]
```

Output:

```
['better sentence', 'as compared']
```

`timeit` results:

```
The slowest run took 4.92 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.74 µs per loop
```

---

Here's another way with `re`.

```
import re
string = "The is a better :: sentence as :: compared to that" 
result = [' '.join(x) for x in re.findall('([\w]+) :: ([\w]+)', string)]
```

Output:

```
['better sentence', 'as compared']
```

`timeit` results:

```
The slowest run took 4.60 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.49 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yeah it works  perfectly! Thanks. Zipping and finding first and last words from each tuple was what I was looking for.

Comment: @ShounakGujarathi If you don't mind, I've added a second solution. Not sure how robust it is compared to the first though.

Comment: i would be curious as to how this stacks up with the re.findall solution  (ie you should post some timeits ... personally i think the re.findall method is much more readable

Comment: @JoranBeasley Added. Not sure what to make of the results.

Comment: @JoranBeasley The one caveat with `re` is it'd have to be edited a little to handle extra whitespaces round the `::` gracefully. That could eat up performance a bit. Edit: Just checked and it's not all that much.

Comment: `(\w+)\s*::` would handle 0 or more whitespace pretty easy

Answer (score 3):

The solution using `re.findall()` function:

```
s = "The is a better :: sentence as :: compared to that"
result = [' '.join(i) for i in re.findall(r'(\w+) ?:: ?(\w+)', s)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['better sentence', 'as compared']
```

Comment: I would probably be more specific in what constitutes a word as Im never really sure what \w means ... but yeah +1 for re.findall

Comment: You and I have the same re solution...  +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

1st) Get indices of the delimiter

```
indices = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(string.split(' ')) if elem == '::']
```

2nd) Join the words around the delimiter

```
for idx in indices:
    print ' '.join(string.split(' ')[idx-1:idx+2:2])

'better sentence'
'as compared'
```